# Проверка символов и сокрытие блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли реализовать подобную проверку? Имеем div в котором будут меняться значения, например, на одной странице выводится 123, на второй 4, на третьей - 23 и т.д.
На странице так же есть второй div в который вложено еще 5 блоков. Мысль такая, если в первом div вписана цифра 1 и 3, то выводится 1 и 3-й блоки и т.д.

Пример HTML кода, для лучшего понимания задачи:

```
<div class="num">145</div>
<div class="cont">
<div id="1">...</div>
<div id="2" class="hide">...</div>
<div id="3" class="hide">...</div>
<div id="4">...</div>
<div id="5">...</div>
</div>
```

То есть, div.cont - статичный блок, который не меняется. На разных страницах будут меняться только цифры в div.num. Соответственно, если каких-то цифер в этом блоке нет, то блоки с соответствующими id должны будут скрываться или добавлять к ним класс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
digs = $('.num').html();
$('.cont>div').each(function() {
  if (!digs.match($(this).attr('id'))) {
    $(this).addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="num">145</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div id="1">1</div>
  <div id="2">2</div>
  <div id="3">3</div>
  <div id="4">4</div>
  <div id="5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Скрипт немного переделаю, так как код был лишь примером, но смысл понятен. Спасибо огромное!